# How to use Hadoop to process video data

Tags: video, hadoop

Now I have some Big Video Data. I want to decode the video data in `hadoop` using `Map/Reduce`. 
What the lib for decoding I want to use is `ffmpeg`. But the function `av_open_input_file` can only read the local file, not on `HDFS`.
 
So if I want to decode the video data, I should initialize the `struct AVFormatContext`. Now I can't get this `struct`. How can I read the header of video file and initialize `AVFormatContext`. And read the video data byte by byte and decode them at last?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to decoded distributively. But ffmpeg can only decode the local video. So I tried to load the file header to initiate the decoder. At last, I failed. Then I found an another solution:fuse_dfs. It can mount HDFS to local filesystem while the data are also stored in distributed filesystem.
You can find some help in this site:
[how to mount hdfs to local file system](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS)